Why does Terraform auth0_branding resource keep failing universal_login validation?
Auth0 provider= 0.39.0
Terraform = 1.5.7
Banging my head against the wall on this one for a couple days. Can't figure out why the universal login liquid file keeps failing Terraform validation, even though the tags exist. Any help or insight would be appreciated.
Error
╷
│ Error: 400 Bad Request: The template must contain a single auth0:head tag and at least one auth0:widget tag.
│ 
│   with auth0_branding.smartwarehousing,
│   on branding.tf line 7, in resource "auth0_branding" "test":
│    7: resource "auth0_branding" "test" {
│ 
╵

Code
resource "auth0_branding" "test" {
  logo_url = var.branding_url

  colors {
    primary         = "#002767"
    page_background = "#ffffff"
  }

  universal_login {
    body = file("${path.module}/setup/html/universal_login/index.liquid")
  }

  depends_on = [
    auth0_custom_domain.custom_domain
  ]
}

I copied the tags directly from Auth0 documentation, and we can post this template directly to auth0 using the API just fine, but when using terraform it fails.
Proof that tags exist:
% cat setup/html/universal_login/index.liquid | grep "{%- auth0:widget -%}"                                                                                      
          {%- auth0:widget -%}
        <div class=\"prompt-wrapper\">{%- auth0:widget -%}</div>
      {%- auth0:widget -%}

% cat setup/html/universal_login/index.liquid | grep "{%- auth0:head -%}"                                                                                            
    <link href=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeface-poppins@1.1.13/index.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" /> {%- auth0:head -%}

